# Cannot find module /chartjs.helpers while using chartjs-plugins-datalabels (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, npm, chart.js, npm-scripts, react-chartjs-2

I am trying to add datalabels on top of my Bar chart

```
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';

<Bar data={chartData} options={opts} plugins={[ChartDataLabels]} />
```

Reference to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68046847/adding-data-labels-inside-charts-in-reactjs-is-not-working/68373429#68373429)

Facing the following issue:

Cant resolve chart.js/helpers in /node_modules/chartjs-plugins-datalabels/dist

[image: dependencies attached]

[image: Detailed error message]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a mismatch of versions. Version 2 of the datalabels plugin is for chart.js version 3 while you are using chart.js version 2. So you either need to update chart.js and the wrapper which does include breaking changes or you need to install version 1.0.0 of the datalabels plugin